# Vue JS: How to make two Vue Instances to work together on the same page?

Tags: vue.js

I created a recipe website, you can find it here https://hungry-vegetarian.com/.
The tab on the [index page](https://github.com/IrinaPenzina/hungry-vegetarian/blob/main/index.html) is a [vue instance](https://github.com/IrinaPenzina/hungry-vegetarian/blob/main/index.js). I'm trying to create a search bar that is also a [vue instance](https://github.com/IrinaPenzina/hungry-vegetarian/blob/main/search.js).

The problem occurs when I try to display searched recipes on the [index page](https://github.com/IrinaPenzina/hungry-vegetarian/blob/main/index.html). It just shows the search result on top of the search bar.

Ideally, only searched recipes should appear on the tab just like they are now but without any indications on top of the tab like Breakfast, Salad, Bakery, etc.

I don't know how to make two objects work together. For now, they work separately without communicating with each other.

[SEARCH](https://github.com/IrinaPenzina/hungry-vegetarian/blob/main/search.js)

```
<div id="search">
        <div class="main-search">
          <h1 class="search-question">What  are you in the mood for?</h1>
          <div class="search-box">
                <input type="text" v-model="searchQuery" class="input-search" placeholder="Bread">
              <button class="btn-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="recipe" v-for="post in filteredList">
            <div v-if="searchQuery">
              <a v-bind:href="post.url" class="recipe-card__card-link" target="_blank">
                <img v-bind:src="post.image" alt="" class="recipe-card__image"/>
                <div class="recipe-card__text-wrapper">
                  <h2 class="recipe-card__title">{{post.name}}</h2>
                  <div class="recipe-card__details-wrapper">
                    <p class="recipe-card__excerpt">{{post.body}}</p>
                    <a v-bind:href="post.url" class="recipe-card__read-more">Read more <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[tab](https://github.com/IrinaPenzina/hungry-vegetarian/blob/main/index.js)

```
<main id="tab">
      <header>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <div id="arrow">
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <li v-for="(tab, tabName) in tabs" :key="tabName">
              <button class="tab" @click="setTabActive(tabName)" :class="{'active': tabName === activeTab}">
                <span class="tab-copy">{{ tabName }}</span>
                <span class="tab-background">
                </span>
              </button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <article>
        <div class="container">
          <transition name="fade" mode="out-in" appear :duration="500">
            <tab-content v-for="(tabContent, t) in tabs" :data="tabContent" :key="'content'+t" v-if="t === activeTab" inline-template>
              <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="recipes" v-for="(recipe, i) in data.recipes" :key="i">
                  <a v-bind:href="recipe.url" class="recipe-card__card-link"></a>
                  <img :src="recipe.image" alt="" class="recipe-card__image">
                  <div class="recipe-card__text-wrapper">
                    <h2 class="recipe-card__title">{{recipe.name}}</h2>
                    <div class="recipe-card__details-wrapper">
                      <p class="recipe-card__excerpt">{{recipe.body}}</p>
                      <a v-bind:href="recipe.url" class="recipe-card__read-more">Read more <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </tab-content>
          </transition>
        </div>
      </article>
    </main>
```

I tried to combine instances search and tab into just one instance tab, but it always gives me a Vue warning:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "searchQuery" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for  class-based components, by initializing the property.

Also, I feel like I can have just the wrong approach to this problem I am trying to solve. Please, any suggestions are welcome. I am stuck.

Comment: Why are you using two separate instances instead of a single one with components?

Comment: The other day someone sent me a pull request with a solution using [pinia] (https://pinia.vuejs.org/). It worked!